# Div has onclick function but the iframe inside the div is not clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have a `div` that has a function and the `iframe` inside this `div`, but my `iframe` is not clickable. Is there any way to make `iframe` clickable and trigger same event or function as the `div` where this `iframe` is inside? I will really appreciate any advice. Thank you

```html
<div id="t1" onclick="myFunction(this, 'test', '')" class="button-hyperlink">
    <h5>Testing</h5>
    <h6>
        <iframe id="content_iframe3" src="test.html" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"
                height="30px" width="200px" name="target-iframe"></iframe>
    </h6>
</div>
```

Function

```js
function myFunction(divid, link) {
    this.clear();
    divid.style.background = "blue";
    //some conditions
}

function clear() {
    for (var i = 0; i < divItems.length; i++) {
        var item = divItems[i];
        item.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this code. (It is slightly diferrent from your `myFunction`.)

```
<div id="t1" onclick="myFunction('t1')" class="button-hyperlink">
    <h5>Testing</h5>
    <h6>
        <iframe id="content_iframe3" src="test.html" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" 
                height="30px" width="200px" name="target-iframe"></iframe>
    </h6>
</div>
```

```
function myFunction(divid) {
    var div=document.getElementById(divid);
    div.style.background = "blue";
}
window.onload=function () {
  var f=document.querySelector("#content_iframe3");     
  f.contentWindow.addEventListener("click", function () {
      myFunction("t1");
  } ); 
};
```